# How to display a (basic) column indicator?

Tags: highlighting, fill-column

Since [fill-column-indicator](https://github.com/alpaker/fill-column-indicator) is no longer actively maintained, how can I visualize the `fill-column`?

The fill-column-indicator package was quite heavy and had compatibility issues with other packages.

#### Possible solutions:

- Enable line highlighting `hl-line-mode` only highlighting up until the `fill-column`.
- Display a character on the current line at the `fill-column`.

... maybe others options I'm unaware of.

#### Insufficient Solutions:

Noting these since I've seen them posted as answers to [similar questions](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/147).

- Displaying a marker on the mode-line:

  *Too far away from the current line to be useful*.
- Using whitespace mode to highlight text beyond the fill column.

  While better than nothing. I'd like to be able to see this limit while typing *(before I exceed it)*.
- [ColumnMarker](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColumnMarker)

  Only highlights columns that contains text, again, no way to see the column indicator before you reach it.

Comment: Emacs master has a branch that is called `fill-column-indicator` that is being developed.  I'm not fond of it because it cannot intersect characters, but it is what it is.  I have been working on feature requests 17684 / 22873 for the past three+ years and anticipate submitting the next draft patch in a week or so; however, it may never be adopted by the powers that be.  As part of 17684 / 22873, I have a visible fill column indicator that *can* intersect characters -- but it is for only GUI versions of Emacs.

Comment: Sure looks like a duplicate to me. Seems like just asking for additional answers.

Comment: Moved own asnwer to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/147/how-can-i-get-a-ruler-at-column-80 suppose this can be closed.