# Highlight single character at column 80

Tags: highlighting, doom, column, highlight-chars

I am trying to highlight just a single character on a line when  it is on the 80th column mark.

I am using Doom Emacs, which did it on in on a previous Emacs version, but I updated my operating system, and I can no longer get it to work.

To be clear, I only want one character at the 80th column mark to be highlighted not a ruler (fill-column-indicator-mode), and not everything after (whitespace-mode), nor the whole line, all of which seem to have solutions. Just one character.

How is this done?

Edit:

As in this image.
[image: Doom Emacs highlighted character at column 80.]
Note: if it was a space at column 80, that would be highlighted as well.

Comment: What should happen when a line is shorter than 80 chars?

Comment: Nothing, maybe I add a screenshot. I thought everyone used this as it came with Doom Emacs when I started using it.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50583/14825) help?

Comment: Yes and no. Looking at it closely I realized I wanted the invert of fill-column which led me to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found the answer, it is called ["hl-fill-column"](https://github.com/laishulu/hl-fill-column), and it is a mode that does the invert of "fill-column-indicator-mode", though I suspect it uses "fill-column-indicator".

It is not listed in init.el of Doom Emacs and seems to have been removed from more recent versions, probably due to some conflicts.